# error: not found: value StartScriptPlugin StartScriptPlugin.stage in Compile := Unit

Tags: scala, heroku, sbt

First I need to say, I'm Scala and SBT beginner so this is my first project with it. I try to deploy scala app on Heroku. I'm getting this error:

```
error: not found: value StartScriptPlugin StartScriptPlugin.stage in Compile := Unit
```

Here is my build.sbt. **What is wrong with it?** I know that is something with StartScriptPlugin.stage in Compile := Unit but I found some examples and they always use it this way. Thanks

```
name := "Survey server" 

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

resolvers ++= Seq("repo.codahale.com" at "http://repo.codahale.com", Classpaths.typesafeResolver)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.3")

StartScriptPlugin.stage in Compile := Unit

EclipseKeys.withSource := true

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
"net.databinder" %% "unfiltered-filter" % "0.6.3", 
"net.databinder" %% "unfiltered-jetty" % "0.6.3", 
"net.databinder.dispatch" %% "core" % "0.9.0", 
"com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.5.0", 
"org.scalaquery" % "scalaquery_2.9.1" % "0.10.0-M1", 
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell SBT that your project uses the StartScriptPlugin. This is done by using the `addSbtPlugin` command in `project/plugins.sbt`. This is all explained in the SBT documentation:
https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Using-Plugins

The documentation for the plugin that you are trying to use even tells you exactly what you need to add to `project/plugins.sbt`. For SBT 0.11, this would be:

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin( "com.typesafe.startscript" % "xsbt-start-script-plugin" % "0.5.2" )
```

See https://github.com/typesafehub/xsbt-start-script-plugin

Comment: For some reason the end of the script above was truncated by SO. Follow the provided link to see the correct script.

Comment: Thank you Regis :) It's working! I did not realize recursive nature of SBT and didn't notice they refer to project/build.sbt and then alter to build.sbt.